# Native Admob Ads in Xamarin.Forms. Are there any ready-made solutions / examples?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, admob, ads

I need to implement Native Ads in Xamarin.Forms. But I did not find any examples on Xamarin.Forms. 
Maybe someone has an example of using Native Ads on Xamarin.Forms and can share.

My example of what I was trying to do:

Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(NativeAd))]
namespace Ads.Droid.Platform.Renderers.Ad
{
    public class NativeAd : AdListener, INativeAd
    {
        Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        NativeExpressAdView mAdView;

       public void Show()
        {   
            var videoOptions = new VideoOptions.Builder().SetStartMuted(false).Build();
            var adOptions = new NativeAdOptions.Builder().SetVideoOptions(videoOptions).Build();
            AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110").WithNativeAdOptions(adOptions).Build();

            var request = new AdRequest.Builder();
            foreach (var item in TestDevice.GetTestDevices())
                request.AddTestDevice(item);

            adLoader.LoadAd(request.Build());   
        }
    }
}
```

or:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(NativeAd))]
namespace Ads.Droid.Platform.Renderers.Ad
{
    public class NativeAd : AdListener, INativeAd
    {
        NativeExpressAdView mAdView;

       public void Show()
        {   
            mAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(Android.App.Application.Context)
            {
                AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110",
                AdSize = AdSize.MediumRectangle
            };
            var request = new AdRequest.Builder();
            foreach (var item in TestDevice.GetTestDevices())
                request.AddTestDevice(item);
            mAdView.LoadAd(request.Build());    
        }
    }
}
```

In iOS didn’t do it, but I also need an example.
Maybe something needs to be changed or completed.
Help me please.

Comment: Hey,Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT This question has been suspended for now. The problem is that there is no Native Ad in the account.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source for implementing Google AdMob Native Ad for Android with new `NativeAdView`.

This source will be in your Shared,

```
public class NativeAdView : ContentView
{
    public NativeAdView()
    {
        this.HeightRequest = 100;
        this.Margin = new Thickness(8, 8, 8, 0);

        SetPlaceholderContent();
    }

    private void SetPlaceholderContent()
    {
        var placeholderGrid = new Grid();
        var placeHolderText = new Label
        {
            Text = "AD",
            FontSize = 48,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            VerticalOptions = new LayoutOptions(LayoutAlignment.Center, true),
            HorizontalOptions = new LayoutOptions(LayoutAlignment.Center, true)
        };

        placeholderGrid.Children.Add(placeHolderText);

        this.Content = placeholderGrid;
    }

}
```

Add below xml in your `Android -> Resources -> create a folder called 'layout' -> native_ad.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">
 
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">
 
            <AbsoluteLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
 
                <com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.MediaView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/ad_media"/>
                
 
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Ad"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:background="#FFCC66"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:padding="4dp" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
 
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">
 
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal">
 
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
 
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ad_app_icon"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
 
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
 
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ad_headline"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                                android:text="Join the dark side!"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
 
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">
 
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ad_advertiser"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="bottom"
                                    android:textSize="14sp"
                                    android:text="Google"
                                    android:textColor="#222222"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
 
                                <RatingBar
                                    android:id="@+id/ad_stars"
                                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:isIndicator="true"
                                    android:numStars="5"
                                    android:stepSize="0.5"
                                    android:rating="4" />
                            </LinearLayout>
 
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
 
                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="#555555"
                        android:id="@+id/ad_body"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nis."
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
 
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/ad_store"
                           android:text="Google Play"
                        android:textColor="#222222"
                         android:textSize="12sp" />
 
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ad_call_to_action"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="0dp"
                        android:text="INSTALL"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
 
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ad_price"
                        android:text="$ 3.49"
                        android:textColor="#222222"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
 
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>
```

Add below source in your Android specific,

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Android.Gms.Ads.NativeAd;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(xxxx.Common.AdsView.NativeAdView), typeof(xxxx.Droid.Helpers.AdsView.NativeAd))]
namespace xxxx.Droid.Helpers.AdsView
{
    public class NativeAd : ViewRenderer
    {

        public NativeAd(Context context) : base(context) { }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(Context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110");

                var listener = new NativeAdLoadedListener();
                listener.OnNativeAdLoaded += (s, ad) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var root = new NativeAdView(Context);
                        var inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                        var adView = (NativeAdView)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.native_ad, root);

                        populateUnifiedNativeAdView(ad, adView);

                        SetNativeControl(adView);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                };

                adLoader.ForNativeAd(listener);
                var requestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                adLoader.Build().LoadAd(requestBuilder.Build());
            }
        }

        private void populateUnifiedNativeAdView(Android.Gms.Ads.NativeAd.NativeAd nativeAd, NativeAdView adView)
        {
            adView.MediaView = adView.FindViewById<MediaView>(Resource.Id.ad_media);

            // Set other ad assets.
            adView.HeadlineView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_headline);
            adView.BodyView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_body);
            adView.CallToActionView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_call_to_action);
            adView.IconView = adView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ad_app_icon);
            adView.PriceView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_price);
            adView.StarRatingView = adView.FindViewById<RatingBar>(Resource.Id.ad_stars);
            adView.StoreView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_store);
            adView.AdvertiserView = adView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_advertiser);

            // The headline and mediaContent are guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
            ((TextView)adView.HeadlineView).Text = nativeAd.Headline;

            // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
            // check before trying to display them.
            if (nativeAd.Body == null)
            {
                adView.BodyView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.BodyView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((TextView)adView.BodyView).Text = nativeAd.Body;
            }

            if (nativeAd.CallToAction == null)
            {
                adView.CallToActionView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.CallToActionView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((Android.Widget.Button)adView.CallToActionView).Text = nativeAd.CallToAction;
            }

            if (nativeAd.Icon == null)
            {
                adView.IconView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else
            {
                ((ImageView)adView.IconView).SetImageDrawable(nativeAd.Icon.Drawable);
                adView.IconView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nativeAd.Price))
            {
                adView.PriceView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.PriceView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((TextView)adView.PriceView).Text = nativeAd.Price;
            }

            if (nativeAd.Store == null)
            {
                adView.StoreView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                adView.StoreView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                ((TextView)adView.StoreView).Text = nativeAd.Store;
            }

            if (nativeAd.StarRating == null)
            {
                adView.StarRatingView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                ((RatingBar)adView.StarRatingView).Rating = nativeAd.StarRating.FloatValue();
                adView.StarRatingView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            if (nativeAd.Advertiser == null)
            {
                adView.AdvertiserView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                ((TextView)adView.AdvertiserView).Text = nativeAd.Advertiser;
                adView.AdvertiserView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }

            // This method tells the Google Mobile Ads SDK that you have finished populating your
            // native ad view with this native ad.
            adView.SetNativeAd(nativeAd);
        }
    }

    public class NativeAdLoadedListener : AdListener, Android.Gms.Ads.NativeAd.NativeAd.IOnNativeAdLoadedListener
    {
        void Android.Gms.Ads.NativeAd.NativeAd.IOnNativeAdLoadedListener.OnNativeAdLoaded(Android.Gms.Ads.NativeAd.NativeAd ad)
        {
            OnNativeAdLoaded?.Invoke(this, ad);
        }

        public EventHandler<Android.Gms.Ads.NativeAd.NativeAd> OnNativeAdLoaded { get; set; }
    }

}
```

That's it, now you can use below code to display the Native Ad on your xaml page.

```
<ContentViews1:NativeAdView HeightRequest="100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `GoogleMobileAds` in iOS. Important the package `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.AdMob`from NuGet.

> in AppDelegate.cs

```
...
using Google.MobileAds;
...

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
   . . .
   MobileAds.Configure("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110 ");
   . . . 
}
```

> in iOS Dependency

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NativeiOSAd))]
namespace XXX.iOS
{
    public class NativeiOSAd:NativeAd
    {

        NativeExpressAdView mAdView;

        public NativeiOSAd()
        {
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            AdSize adSize = new AdSize();
            adSize.Size = new CGSize(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, 100);

            mAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(adSize)
            {
                AdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110"
            };

            Request request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();


            mAdView.LoadRequest(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget add the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia`, and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` exceptions to your app's Info.plist file to disable ATS restrictions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer