# Xamarin iOS AdMob NativeAd AdLoader Delegate Never Called

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, admob, unifiednativeadview

I am trying to implement the iOS renderer for a XF view to display native ads.
I can't seem to load the native ad.
Using:

```
try
{
    loader.Delegate = new MyAdLoaderDelegate(renderer);
    loader.LoadRequest(request);

}catch(Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

Debug.WriteLine("Loading: " + loader.IsLoading);
```

The delegate is getting set properly and after the `loader.LoadRequest()` call the `loader.IsLoading==true`, but the methods on `MyAdLoaderDelegate` are never called. No exception is thrown by the call to `LoadRequest()` either.

Here is my delegate class:

```
private class MyAdLoaderDelegate : NSObject, IUnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate
{
    private readonly AdMobUnifiedNativeAdRenderer _renderer;

    public MyAdLoaderDelegate(AdMobUnifiedNativeAdRenderer renderer)
    {
        _renderer = renderer;
    }

    public void DidReceiveUnifiedNativeAd(AdLoader adLoader, UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DidReceiveUnifiedNativeAd");
    }
    public void DidFailToReceiveAd(AdLoader adLoader, RequestError error)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DidFailToReceiveAd");
        //base.DidFailToReceiveAd(adLoader, error);
    }

    public void DidFinishLoading(AdLoader adLoader)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DidFinishLoading");
        //base.DidFinishLoading(adLoader);
    }
}
```

Curiously too the delegate class would not work when inheriting from `UnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate`, the loader delegate was always null. Implementing the interface works though, but no methods are ever hit.

Not sure where to go from here.

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobUnifiedNativeAd), typeof(AdMobUnifiedNativeAdRenderer))]
namespace XXXX.Mobile.iOS.CustomRenderers.NativeAds
{
    public class AdMobUnifiedNativeAdRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdMobUnifiedNativeAd,UnifiedNativeAdView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdMobUnifiedNativeAd> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                CreateAdView(this);
            }
        }

        private void CreateAdView(AdMobUnifiedNativeAdRenderer renderer)
        {

            if (Element == null) return;

            var loader = new AdLoader(
                Element.AdUnitId,
                GetVisibleViewController(),
                new AdLoaderAdType[] { AdLoaderAdType.UnifiedNative },
                new AdLoaderOptions[] {
                    new NativeAdViewAdOptions {PreferredAdChoicesPosition = AdChoicesPosition.TopRightCorner}
                });

            var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
            request.TestDevices = new string[] { Request.SimulatorId };

            UnifiedNativeAdView adView = null;
            try
            {
                adView = MyUnifiedAdView.Create();
                SetNativeControl(adView);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            if (adView == null) return;

            try
            {
                loader.Delegate = new MyAdLoaderDelegate(renderer);
                loader.LoadRequest(request);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Loading: " + loader.IsLoading);
        }

        private UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
        {
            var windows = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows;
            foreach (var window in windows)
            {
                if (window.RootViewController != null)
                {
                    return window.RootViewController;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me the other codes in your renderer? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624172/native-admob-ads-in-xamarin-forms-are-there-any-ready-made-solutions-examples) is example about using dependency service to show ads. Also check if you has use the right key.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT added complete renderer code for you.

Comment: Did you use override  keyword when inheriting from UnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes I used override when using UnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate. The problem I have is the delegate is never invoked and because of the way the library is organized I have no visibility into what is happening once LoadRequest is called. Is there any compiler switch to allow more verbose debug logging?

Comment: Could you provide an example on Github that we can try to test with?

Comment: Just put loader as a class level variable and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered identical problem. Solution was kinda simple.

LoadRequest needs to be called in main thread! This solved the issue.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { 
loader.LoadRequest(Request.GetDefaultRequest());
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I actually figured this out a long time ago but forgot to circle back and answer my own question.