# Xamarin.iOS app with Google AdMob package gets 'The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found'

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, admob

I am working up a new Xamarin.iOS app is VS for Mac with Google AdMob support.  Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624172/native-admob-ads-in-xamarin-forms-are-there-any-ready-made-solutions-examples/52640039#52640039) post and [that](https://xamarinhelp.com/admob-xamarin-forms-display-google-ads-mobile-app/) post.  I get

```
The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found...
```

Steps to repro in *Visual Studio for Mac* are

1. Create a new project using the Xamarin.iOS Single View App template.  Take all the defaults.
2. Use the NuGet Package Manager to add Xamarin.Google.IOS.MobileAds and its prerequisites.
3. Open AppDelegate.cs and add the line

   using Google.MobileAds;
4. Build the project.

My VS for Mac is up to date in the stable channel.  Xcode and MacOS are up to date.

What is needed to get such a project in VS for Mac to recognize the reference?  (I recommend trying proposed solutions on a project created using the repro steps above or trying some other technique in a Xamarin.iOS project in VS for Mac before posting.)

[image: example of issue]

Comment: I tried your steps on my side and it works well. Can you please reopen your VS for Mac and reinstall the Xamarin.Google.IOS.MobileAds again to see if the error still there?

Comment: OK, I tried that.  Same problem.  You're using VS for Mac and not Visual Studio on a PC?

Comment: Yes, I test with a VS for Mac and in a new project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my VS for Mac was messed up (across several dot upgrades, hmmm).  After the latest upgrade (to 8.6 build 4520) I started another solution and this time the process of adding NuGet packages and getting references in the project works seamlessly.

Should VS for Mac fail again, a workaround is to edit the .csproj file and add the references manually:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    ...
    <Reference Include="Firebase.Core">
      <HintPath><your path>\.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\6.6.6\lib\xamarinios10\Firebase.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Google.MobileAds">
      <HintPath<your path>\.nuget\packages\xamarin.google.ios.mobileads\7.57.0\lib\xamarinios10\Google.MobileAds.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  ...
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds">
    <Version>7.24.1</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```